# Passing object in another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, loops

I have two `arrays` which is the `result.new_record` and the `result.leave_type` i have a `loop`, `$(result.new_record).each(function(index, data)` i want to include the `result.leave_type` and put the data of the `result.leave_type` to the table `tbl_tag` but the data says `undefined` but the data of `result.new_record` was shown only the `result.leave_type` is undefined.

here's the result of 'console.log` and the table.

[image]

Result of `html += '<td>'+ JSON.stringify(leavetype) +'</td>';`
[image]

**jQuery Code**

```
    success :   function(result)
        {
            result = JSON.parse(result);
            var html = "";


            $(result.new_record).each(function(index, data)
            {           
                console.log(result.leave_type);
                html += tbl_tag(data,result.leave_type);
            });
            $(".tbl-tag").html(html);
            remove_tag();
        }



function tbl_tag(data,leavetype)
    {
        var html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + data.payroll_employee_title_name + ' ' + data.payroll_employee_first_name + ' ' + data.payroll_employee_middle_name  + ' ' + data.payroll_employee_last_name  + ' ' + data.payroll_employee_suffix_name  + ' <input type="hidden" name="employee_tag[]" value="'+data.payroll_employee_id+'"></td>';
        html += '<td>'+ leavetype.payroll_leave_hours_cap +'</td>';
        html += '<td><a href="#" class="btn-remove-tag" data-content="'+data.payroll_employee_id+'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        return html;

    }
```

Comment: did you try with html += this.tbl_tag(data,result.leave_type); ?

Comment: `var html = "";
            result.leave_type` the second one will produce an error

Comment: Can you give me the console log data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the below line in your `tbl_tag` function from

```
html += '<td>'+ leavetype.payroll_leave_hours_cap +'</td>';
```

to

```
html += '<td>'+ leavetype[0].payroll_leave_hours_cap +'</td>';
```

As you are passing Array to function you will select the 1st element by using `[0]` and then the value by using the property name like `leavetype[0].payroll_leave_hours_cap`